# How do I get the default constructor value in a function

Tags: c#, default-constructor

```
AppXmlLogWritter objParameterized = new AppXmlLogWritter(1234, "LogApplication", "LogFilepath");

AppXmlLogWritter objParmeterlessConstr = new AppXmlLogWritter();

objParameterized.WriteXmlLog("0", "LogFlag");
```

How do I get the default constructor value in this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call constructor in your other constructor as shown below, by this()

```
    public AppXmlLogWritter(int intLogIDPrefix, string strLogApplication, string strLogFilePath)
          :this()
    {
        LogIDPrefix = intLogIDPrefix;
        LogApplication = strLogApplication;
        LogFilePath = strLogFilePath;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

To call the base constructor of a class from another constructor you use the `this` keyword like so:

```
public AppXmlLogWritter(int intLogIDPrefix, string strLogApplication, string strLogFilePath) 
    : this()
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear what value you are talking about, but if you refer to `randomNumber`, you already have acsess to it *inside* class.

If the function you're going to call is the function that consumes type `AppXmlLogWritter`, you can define property like:

```
public class AppXmlLogWritter{


        public int RandomNumber {get;set}; //PUBLIC PROPERTY


        public AppXmlLogWritter()
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            RandomNumber = random.Next(9999);
            LogDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd HHmmss");
        }

     .... ..
     .... ..       

}
```

Comment: what about date time i m also getting date time blank in function

Comment: @lax: if your problem is that your default ctor is not called, just add `this()` to declaration of parametrized ctor.